# Apply jQuery function to appearing elements individually

Tags: jquery, this

I'm using [jGravity](https://github.com/tinybigideas/jGravity) on a loading page. The page loads different divs during the page load and I want to apply jGravity to every appearing div, but only once. This is the code I have so far, but it applies jGravity to every div.bubble everytime, so it messes up everything.

```
 function showDiv() {
     if(counter == 0 ) { counter ++; return; }
     $('#whatsapp').find('#bubble-' + counter).show().jGravity({ 
        target: 'div.bubble',
        ignoreClass: 'ignoreMe',
        weight: 25, 
        depth: 5, 
        drag: true 
    });
     counter ++;
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

I can't test at the moment but I think this would work for your needs:

```
function showDiv() {
    if(counter == 0 ) { counter ++; return; }
    $('#whatsapp').find('#bubble-' + counter + ':not(.ignoreMe)').addClass('ignoreMe').show().jGravity({ 
        target: 'div.bubble',
        ignoreClass: 'ignoreMe',
        weight: 25, 
        depth: 5, 
        drag: true 
    });
    counter ++
```

It adds a class `ignoreMe` to each item as it goes and ignores the items with that class afterwards using the [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo class.